# Full width subviews of uiscrollview with auto layout in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm having a problem with making subviews of a `UIScrollView` be the same with as the root view. The `UIScrollView` has constraint similar to H:|-0-[scrollview]-0-| and V:|-0-[scrollview]-0-|. All the subviews has horizontal constraints similar to H:|-0-[view]-0-|.

Still, unless I explicitly set a width of at least one subview, the scrollview and all subviews resizes to the smallast possible width of the subviews (in this case with intrinsic content size of the UIButton). It does this even if I explicitly set a width of the `UIScrollView` itself.

I would like to avoid setting explicit widths, since this UI is shared between both iPhone (4, 5, 6) and iPad.

How can I make the horisontal contentSize of the `UIScrollView` be the same with as the parent root view and still have the layout work in IB?

[image: Example of messed up layout]

Comment: You can't use constraints to layout the direct subviews of a scrollview. You have to either do them manually or place them inside a container view... that is laid out manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more years of iOS development and auto layout, I found that fixing this is quite easy. Just set and equal width constraint between the collection view and the root view, ie the superview of the scrollview.